# Message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

Tags: django

Where my code contains problem? I can't get it
Now I am unable to see the rendered template which belongs to below url.
and I see this error 
Message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

## models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name = 'message_sender', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name = 'message_reciever', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.message}'


    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args = [str(self.sender.pk)])
```

## views.py

```
class SendMessageView(CreateView):
    form_class = Message
    template_name = 'send_message.html'
```

## urls.py

```
path('<int:pk>/send', SendMessageView.as_view(), name = 'send_message'),
```

Comment: `form_class = Message` you pass here a model not a form.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms

Comment: Thanks I should have used model instead of form_class thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace **form_class** with **model**

```
class SendMessageView(CreateView):
    model = Message
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'send_message.html'
```

You can get more info at [more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/)

Comment: Thank you my friend. I can't really remember what did I do at that moment and what was the problem. So I can't Accept your answer but I appreciate your answer.